# C++ Авторизация на сайте и взаимодействие с ним

Tags: c++, curl

Есть сайт, на котором нужно пройти авторизацию. После авторизации откроется страница с двумя кнопками. Мне нужно:

1. Программно пройти авторизацию на сайте.
2. Иметь возможность программно "нажимать" на кнопки.

Захват экрана не подходит.
Нужно что-то наподобие такого:

```
bool authentication(const std::string& login, const std::string& password)
{
    //Если не залогинился false.
    //Иначе - true.
}

void pressButtonLeft()
{
}

void pressButtonRight()
{
}
```

В интернете нашел оболочку на libcurl - [cpr](https://docs.libcpr.org). Там был приведен пример с аутентификацией. Возможно я что-то не так понял под словом "аутентификация", ведь я достаточно далекий от веба человек, но все же я попытался сделать так(тут пример с почтой яндекса):

```
cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{ "https://passport.yandex.ru/auth/" }, 
        cpr::Authentication{ "login", "password" });
std::cout << r.text << std::endl;
```

В [примере на crp](https://docs.libcpr.org/introduction.html#authentication) они получали ответ вот такого вида:

```
{
  "authenticated": true,
  "user": "user"
}
```

Я же получаю совсем другое:

[image: Часть текста, который выводится в консоль.]

Причем я получаю такой ответ в случае когда ввожу и правильные и не правильные данные. Может ли мне кто-нибудь объяснить или хотя бы намекнуть что делать?

Comment: ¿Адрес `https://passport.yandex.ru/auth` точно был взят из документации к web api яндекса? Это же по ходу их страница авторизации пользователей.

Comment: Вы правы, это страница авторизации пользователей. Сейчас попробую из их api вять.

Comment: Хорошо, если есть задокументированный api - понятно, но есть ли способ пройти авторизацию, если никакой информации по api нет?

Comment: Ну в таком случае следует попробовать авторизоваться вручную и посмотреть в отладчике браузера, что куда там передается. А вообще это скорее потребует использования Selenium WebDriver, а не просто curl.